# Tailwind CSS "border" class does not exist

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am currently upgrading to TailwindCss V3.3.4. When I try to build the application I get this error:

```
Rebuilding...
CssSyntaxError: tailwindcss: {project file directory}\src\tailwind\source.css:12:13: The `border` class does not exist. If `border` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.
    at Input.error ({project file directory}\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:106:16)
    at AtRule.error ({project file directory}\node_modules\postcss\lib\node.js:115:32)
    at processApply ({project file directory}\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\lib\expandApplyAtRules.js:380:29)
    at {project file directory}\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\lib\expandApplyAtRules.js:538:9
    at {project file directory}\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\processTailwindFeatures.js:57:50
    at async Object.Once ({project file directory}\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\cli\build\plugin.js:250:17)
    at async LazyResult.runAsync ({project file directory}\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:261:11)
    at async build ({project file directory}\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\cli\build\index.js:49:9) {
reason: 'The `border` class does not exist. If `border` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.'
```

I've also tried to comment out the lines where **border class** appears, and same error I get for **shadow class**. This was not a problem before the upgrade. I know the **border and shadow class** exists in the component classes of tailwindcss but why does this happen here? Anybody have the same experience?

Below is the screenshot of my main.css file.

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is it a Node.js project?

Comment: angular 14 project

Comment: Clear the `node cache` and reinstall `node_modules` folder after deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

CSS modules are always processed independently by build tools which means that Tailwind is running from scratch in isolation on each CSS module, and on your main.css file.

Define any classes you want to @apply in your CSS modules in your tailwind.config.js file as plugins instead of defining them in your main.css file. Then those classes are guaranteed to be visible to any CSS file that is using the same Tailwind config:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    function ({ addUtilities }) {
      addUtilities({
        '.nav-item': {
          '@apply border shadow text-xs': {},
        },
      })
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I get that. But the problem is, border and shadow class exists in tailwind components. So I think I do not need to define it again. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-width and https://tailwindcss.com/docs/box-shadow

Comment: This is probably not the best solution but try defining any classes you want to @apply in your CSS modules in your tailwind.config.js.